# Passenger install fails. RAM too low?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger, vps

I have been trying to install Passanger for apache on my VPS (running Ubuntu 10.10) and it seems to fail due to g++ as it fails at the point it compiles the module. The installation hangs for a while then:

```
g++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
```

After looking around on the net it seems this could be due to a lack of memory (I only have 256mb).

Is there any way around this? Or, is this in fact probably not the problem? I just need this server for a few days and so far it has been such a mess around just setting everything up so I'm not sure I really want to have to start again with a high RAM VPS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the debian package instead of building passenger yourself (`apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger`).

256M seems pretty tight for a rails site though.  I can't imagine you being able to run more than one or two passenger children (my passenger apache instances are using over 200M each).

Comment: That package doesn't seem to be available. Do I need to add an additional source to get it? Yes I agree its pretty small but will probably be replaced within the next couple of days. Just need a test run before I go up in price.

Comment: @Oetzi, it is in the universe repo, so you'll have to enable that if you haven't already.  http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/libapache2-mod-passenger

Comment: I managed to install it via the deb package. Would you be able to give me one last hand and give me some advice on what I add to my apache config? It seems I missed the tutorial contained within the passenger installation.

Comment: @Oetzi: maybe you need to enable the module?  `a2enmod passenger`.  I'm not using the debian package right now, so I'm afraid I can't tell you much more.  (ServerFault may know better).  You could also try checking `/usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-passenger`.  Also don't forget to restart apache after installing/enabling the module.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem, too. Then I tried to install the Debian package. But this package is used with Ruby 1.8 and is not compatible with 1.9 (I got problems with writing `hash_name: value` instead of `:hash_name => value`.

I'm trying to upgrade my VPS, but still looking for a way not to do so